# Remote Connect to MySql Blocked by IPTABLES

Tags: mysql, port, iptables

I've searched through the internet, specifically here, but can't find a solution to my problem.

The closest I've come to are the following, but checking my iptables, they don't seem to apply:

https://superuser.com/questions/1290353/iptables-blocking-remote-mysql-connection
https://superuser.com/questions/791509/mysql-isnt-accepting-remote-connections

I have a virtual server by STRATO, the thing bombed out last week and after a lot of headaches and long nights I have it back online and rebuilt. Before it died I was able to connect to my MariaDb / MySQL server remotely using Navicat. Since the rebuild, it no longer works.

1. The firewall is set up correctly to accept connections from my IP, deny from all other externals
2. The database server is also set up to accept connections form my IP, deny all from other externals
3. The database user has full rights for the connection, and triple checked the credentials
4. A check of the iptables using # iptables -L -x -v -n gives the following:

   Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)

   ```
   pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    947   225118 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
      0        0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW reject-with tcp-reset
    156     6296 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state INVALID
      0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
     15      780 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8443
      0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8880
      4      192 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
     98     4096 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
      1       40 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21
      3      156 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       x.x.x.x         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
      0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       x.x.x.x         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
     14      768 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
      0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25
      1       60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:465
      0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:110
      0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:995
      0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:143
      0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:993
      0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:106
     15      780 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       x.x.x.x         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
      0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       x.x.x.x         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
      1       40 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
      1       40 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5432
      0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9008
      0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9080
      0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
      0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
      0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
    423    21880 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
      0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:1194
      0        0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
      0        0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
      4      202 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8 code 0
    297    13450 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   ```

(where x.x.x.x is the authorized IP addresses)

When I attempt the login using Navicat, I get the following error:

2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (10061 'Unknown error')

Which indicates the network connection was refused.

Question: Does the order of the rules in iptables matter? i.e., Is the DROP overriding the ACCEPT because it comes second?

Thanks for any info or advice in advance!

Edit: Running CENTOS 7 (64-bit) and using Plesk Obsidian (and connecting through SSH)

Comment: Check `netstat -nat` output and verify that MySQL is actually waiting for TCP connections. Rules' order does matter but you seem to have it right (ACCEPT trusted IP(s) before DROPing everything else).

Comment: Thanks, there lies the problem. It is listening to 127.0.0.1:3306 on tcp6 only, now to figure out how to have it listen to port 3306 in tcp.

Comment: Search for `bind-address` in your `my.cnf` configuration file.

Comment: Thanks, that's my next step, will try this evening when the customers are asleep...(this is a test server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Cascader, the tip worked.

In the my.cnf file was:

bind-address = ::ffff:127.0.0.1

I changed it to 0.0.0.0 and then restarted the server and I have access.

Appreciate the comments, thanks!